# how to manipulate results from onBackPressed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, onactivityresult, onbackpressed

I'm trying to develop a simple scoreKeeper app. The problem is I don't know how can I manipulate the results from onBackPressed.
I mean to add or substract. I tried to convert into an integer and to display in a textView but that didn't work.

PS: to receive data from intent and simple display on the screen I succeeded.

Here is my code:
that's an example from my second intent which works fine

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent i2 = new Intent();
        i2.putExtra("message2", mEditText.getText().toString());
        setResult(RESULT_OK, i2);
```

and  MainActivity

```
if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mSecondscore.setText(data.getStringExtra("message2"));
```

but I want something else as I said
here is my code:

```
public void onBackPressed() {

                Intent i = new Intent();
                i.putExtra("message", mEditText.getText().toString());
                setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
                Toast.makeText(this, "You added " + mEditText.getText().toString() + " points", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
```

and MainActivity

```
     if (requestCode == 1  && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

  /*          String a = data.getStringExtra("message");
           int i = Integer.parseInt(a);
           String b = data.getStringExtra("message5");
             int z = Integer.parseInt(b);
             int fResult = i - z;
            String firstResult = Integer.toString(fResult);
            mFirstScore.setText......
  */

            textV.setText(data.getStringExtra("message"));
            int a = Integer.parseInt(textV.getText().toString());
            int b = a + 10;
            mFirstScore.setText(Integer.toString(b));
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code you have posted; Error is in below line

```
mFirstScore.setText(Integer.toString(b));
```

Use below code

```
mFirstScore.setText(String.valueOf(b));
```

> For the error you have commented You might be missing below code

```
    TextView textV= findViewById(R.id.your_id);
```

`your_id` is id you have assigned in XML.

Comment: that;s the error what i receive  : method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference. That's a common error when a textView is not associated with an id. And i dont have an id associated :| . I only declared the TextView! How can i "cath" the data into a String and then to convert into an integer

Comment: that is because your textview is null. You need to declare it and assign id by `findViewbyId(R.id.your_id)`. Check my updated answer

Comment: You are right and i thank you for your patience. As i said i declared TextView ,because this example i found on the web, without assigning it. As you see my code how can i receive data from the intent other then TextView?